# restore Button text and visibility when activity is reCreated

Tags: android, android-activity

My app uses one activity and many fragments, the activity which extends AppCompatActivity inflates an xml file which has a LinearLayout among
other ViewGroups, the purpose of this LinearLayout is to hold 3 buttons not all are visible at start.

In code, I change the view of LinearLayout and 
the view and texts of some of its buttons depending on the action taken in the current fragment. However their state is not maintained when the 
activity is reCreated after phone home key press.
Saving visibility and text of each button every time one gets chnaged in SharedPreferences is too misssy, so I tried the below code but failed.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mMainButtons_LL != null) {
            mMainButtons_LL = (LinearLayout) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mainButtons");
        } else {
            mMainButtons_LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_buttons_LL);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("mainButtons", (Serializable) mMainButtons_LL);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.your_layout); // << replace your layout id here
    mMainButtons_LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_buttons_LL);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mMainButtons_LL.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("visibility"));
        mMainButtons_LL.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("visibility", mMainButtons_LL.getVisibility());
    outState.putString("text", mMainButtons_LL.getText.toString());
}
```

Comment: The ide complains that savedInstanceState.getInt("visibility") must be one of view.Visible, view.Invisible, view.Gone

Comment: um, I'm not sure about the complaint but you always can use switch/case when `putInt` and `getInt` to put/get `View.VISIBLE` and so on. But you get the idea of the difference between my code and yours.

Comment: did you mean: int vis = savedInstanceState.getInt("mainBtVis");
            mMainButtons_LL.setVisibility(vis == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : vis == 4 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.GONE); and do that for all the children view in the LinearLayout?